# passing file in mount options

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel

I am writing a stackable file system which requires some database file. I am thinking of taking it as mount time argument and then reading it's content into private field of superblock of mounted FS. Precisely I intend to do this:

```
mount -t wrapfs -o pattdb=database.db /some/mounted/point /mount/point
```

Here I'm having problem in figuring out where does(in what field of FS does it reside) the file database.db go?

Comment: `mount` the thing `/some/mounted/point` to `/mount/point` as filesystem type `wrapfs`, and tell `wrapfs` to use the option `pattdb=database.db`. Refer to wrapfs' documentation for what that `pattdb` thing means.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by “field of FS”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mount time argument with -o option is received in raw_data field of wrapper file system's mount function.

```
struct dentry *wrapfs_mount(struct file_system_type *fs_type, int flags,
            const char *dev_name, void *raw_data)
```

This function is defined in main.c and for the case above, raw_data points to string pattdb=database.db.